# Update Query in SQL using Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, inner-join, insert-update

I am using SQL UPDATE statement with a JOIN clause.

Whenever I update the table, same data is being updated for all the rows.

Below is the SQL query which is used to update the table

```
update table3 set 
[C1]=TABLE2.CUSTOMER_ID,
[C2]=TABLE2.LOAN_AMOUNT,
[C3]=TABLE2.SOURCE,
[C4]=TABLE2.AMT,
[C5]=TABLE2.REG_NO,
FROM TABLE2 
INNER JOIN TABLE1  ON TABLE1.CID = TABLE2.CUSTOMER_ID
where TABLE2.CUSTOMER_ID IN (SELECT CID FROM TABLE1)
```

When I select the above query using select statement the data is not duplicated. Here is the below statement.

```
select 
[C1]=TABLE2.CUSTOMER_ID,
[C2]=TABLE2.LOAN_AMOUNT,
[C3]=TABLE2.SOURCE,
[C4]=TABLE2.TEAM_MEMBER,
[C5]=TABLE2.TEAM_LEADER,
FROM TABLE2 
INNER JOIN TABLE1  ON TABLE1.CID = TABLE2.CUSTOMER_ID
where TABLE2.CUSTOMER_ID IN (SELECT CID FROM TABLE1)
```

Let me know what is the issue in the update query, since the select statement is working fine.

Comment: You need a condition between table3 and either table1 or table2, such as `WHERE table3.someid = table2.someotherid`  Without it, every row from your select is being applied to every row in table3.

Comment: @MatBailie; Thanks. I have tried to add the condition  "INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.[C1] = table2.CUSTOMER_ID" but the results are same. I,e data is duplicated (every row are same)

Comment: You have no correlation with rows in `table3` so every row is being updated. You should not be updating the same column you are correlating on!

Comment: Pay close attention to the fact that I SAID to put it in the `WHERE` clause (a correlation as Stu mentioned) but you instead used a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

For a joined update, you specify the table to update *as part of the `FROM`* clause, then reference it at the top with its alias:

> I note the `WHERE` clause is entirely unnecessary once you have the join

```sql
update t3
set 
 [C1] = t2.CUSTOMER_ID,
 [C2] = t2.LOAN_AMOUNT,
 [C3] = t2.SOURCE,
 [C4] = t2.AMT,
 [C5] = t2.REG_NO,
FROM TABLE2 t2
INNER JOIN TABLE1 t1 ON t1.CID = t2.CUSTOMER_ID
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.[C1] = t2.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried using the below syntax. But the results are same `code` UPDATE TABLE3 SET 
[C1]=TABLE2.CUSTOMER_ID,
[C2]=TABLE2.LOAN_AMOUNT,
[C3]=TABLE2.SOURCE,
[C4]=TABLE2.TEAM_MEMBER,
[C5]=TABLE2.TEAM_LEADER,
FROM TABLE3 T3
INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T3.C1 = T1.CUSTOMER_ID
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.CID = T1.CUSTOMER_ID `code`

Comment: @KarthickSamganghi But that's not what this answer suggested. The answer has `UPDATE T3` and so refers to the instance in the joins, but you instead changed that to `UPDATE TABLE3` which creates a second independent reference to that table. Try doing what's in the answer.

Comment: @KarthickSambanghi Indeed, follow precisely what I wrote, don't start inventing your own syntax

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments you could try this...

```
UPDATE
  table3
SET
  [C2]=TABLE2.LOAN_AMOUNT,
  [C3]=TABLE2.SOURCE,
  [C4]=TABLE2.AMT,
  [C5]=TABLE2.REG_NO,
FROM
  table2
INNER JOIN
  table1
    ON table1.CID = table2.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE
  table3.C1 = table2.CUSTOMER_ID
```

I've also noted that on more than one occasion you've tried a suggestion given to you, but modified what was suggested. In making the modification you them break what you were being advised to do.

1). If you're trying code suggested by someone, don't modify it. Especially if you don't fully understand the consequences of the modification.

2). If you need to modify it because your real world scenario is slightly different from your simplified example in your question, mock up a test environment that exactly matches your question. (Modify the test area, not the answers.)

I strongly advise reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Once you've read it, mock up an example on something like dbfiddle.uk and edit your question to refer to that fiddle.

That way the answers given to you can be tested on the exact same environment. There will be no need to modify code from answers. It will also allow you to more clearly demonstrate the behaviour you require, by stipulating the output required for the example input.

You may be hesitant to make that effort. But without it you get in to the mess you're in of misinterpreting answers given to you. Also, if YOU can't make that effort, why should we?

For example...

Using the pattern from my answer:

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4bbc0ccfe160f380593355bfee46abb3

Using the pattern from @charlieface's answer:

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2fec38953df53814d21558c9fd970a1d

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is help to update the sql statement using joins:

```
UPDATE tablename  
INNER JOIN tablename  
ON tablename.columnname = tablename.columnname  
SET tablenmae.columnnmae = tablenmae.columnname;
```