# T-SQL, I'm trying to update a table with a CTE, and a join on that CTE, but I get the result for all rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to use the following code to update my underlying table, `FinancialsTest`:

```
with AddressCTE as 
( 
    select person_id, address_line 
    from FinancialsTest
)
Update AddressCTE 
set address_line = y.address_line 
from AddressCTE x
join Demographics y on x.person_id = y.person_id
```

The result I get is the same address line repeated for every row, so it looks like the join isn't working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your CTE is completely redundant here, you may as well join to the table

Comment: A CTE for an `UPDATE` can be a good idea to simplify the logic and allow you to test before updating, but then only if you actually put the `JOIN` in there too. That is, `WITH AddressCTE AS (SELECT ft.person_id, ft.address_line, d.address_line AS new_address_line FROM FinancialsTest ft JOIN Demographics d ON ft.person_id = d.person_id) UPDATE AddressCTE SET address_line = new_address_line`.

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/68595587/14868997 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/72076254/14868997

Answer (score 1):

The query proposed by [jeroen mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) is better, it avoids you to use a CTE.

But if you need a CTE in another context (with more criteria in the CTE), you must specify the alias of the table to update, ie x:

```
with AddressCTE as 
( 
    select person_id, address_line 
    from FinancialsTest
)
update x
set address_line = y.address_line 
from AddressCTE x
join Demographics y on x.person_id = y.person_id
```